# Will domain change affect my pagerank?

Tags: domains, pagerank

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming a domain and preserving PageRank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/renaming-a-domain-and-preserving-pagerank)

I have two blogger's blog. (http://chankeypathak.blogspot.com and http://javaenthusiastic.blogspot.com)

One blog has PR 3 and the other blog has PR 2.

I want to buy the domain for both blogs so that they will become

http://chankeypathak.com/ and http://javaenthusiastic.com/

I will follow all the procedures that Blogger suggests so that all the visitors to http://chankeypathak.blogspot.com will be redirected to http://chankeypathak.com/ and same for the java's blog.

I just want to know that whether this will affect my pagerank or not? I want my PR to remain same and not to be change because of domain change.

Let me know. Thank you.

PS: I don't know whether one person is allowed to post his site's URL in questions or not. If it is not allowed then you may edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at some other blogs that have used the custom domain feature, I see that they have a 301 redirect from the old blogspot URL to the new custom domain URL. I don't know if this is default or something you'll have to configure but this is the correct way to do the redirect and keep your SEO and Page Rank intact.

After you have set up your new custom domain you can check if the redirection is in place by using an [online tool](http://web-sniffer.net/) to view the server responce headers. When viewing the new URL you should get a 200 OK response. For the old URL you should get a 301 redirect responce.