# SEO implications of domain name change

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank)

Will changing a domain name of a popular web-site result in any SEO implications or will 301 redirects make the site stay exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also tell google about the change of address directly, through google webmaster tools, its worth baring in mind that when you do the 301 you need to make a 301 from each page to the new page so you would have oldsite.com/about redirect to newsite.com/about rather than all pages on oldsite.com redirecting to the newsite.com home page.

In my experience you will see a drop of traffic but it tends to normalize after a week and then your back to normal

Comment: Thanks! So you experienced only 1 week drop of traffic? How much drop in percentages?

Comment: not to much as google still had the old site indexed and the 301s were set up correctly so all the traffic google sent to the old site just got passed straight to the new 1

Answer (score 0):

It may have some implications, but not because of the 301 redirects (if done correctly).

If you are worried about the new domain name: [How important is it to have keywords in a domain name? by Matt Cutts @ Google](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAWFv43qubI)