# Changing domain name - what are the practical steps involved

Tags: domains, apache, redirects, apache2, domain-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank)

I launched a website a couple of years ago, bright eyed and bushy tailed, with dreams of conquering the world. Unfortunately it wasn't to be. Now, that I am a bit older and wiser, I have spent some money on branding and creating more quality content etc, I am re-branding and relaunching the site with a new domain name.

Although the traffic on the old site is laughable (i.e. non-existent), there are a few pages of good information on there and I don't want to lose any "juice" those pages may have gained because web crawlers have been seeing it for a few years now.

OK, the upshot of all that is this: I want to change my domain name from example.com to example.org. I am maintaining the same friendly urls I had before, only the domain name part of the url will change, so that any traffic coming to the old page will be forwarded/redirected? to the new page seamlessly.

How do I go about achieving this (i.e. what are the steps I need to carry out, and to minimize any "disruption" to any credibility the existing site has with Googlebot etc?

I am running Apache 2.x on a headless Linux (Ubuntu) server.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that example.com redirects to example.org, Apache can be rather easily configured to do this, for example using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / http://example.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Turns out this dosen't work. Please see my new question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38451/apache-config-file-redirect-permanent-gives-403-error