# Why does my main domain sill show up as addon domain?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank)

I made my addon domain as a main domain, but Google search still show my new main domain as  addon domain. What do i need to do to repair that? Do I need to use Webmasters tool to delete my old main domain or what? I really need help.

Comment: How does Google "show my new main domain as addon domain"? Google shouldn't be able to tell the difference - they should be two separate domains as far as Google is concerned. (?)

Comment: changed my addon domain to main domain, but google doesn't see my new domain as main..It is still indexof my old main domain. I read that is should use webmaster tool to delete my old main domain. Is that correct or not?

Comment: So you've basically moved your site from one domain to another. The fact that it was an addon domain is irrelevant as far as Google is concerned (and confuses your question a little). This earlier question would seem to cover the same: [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank). The key is the 301 redirect and _time_. It does take time.

Comment: my old main domain NAME1 was changed with addon domain NAME2. And now when i make search it shows NAME1 / and folder for NAME 2. I hope now i made my self clear

Comment: That is presumably how you used to access your site, ie. `http://NAME1/NAME2`? It looks as though you need to set up a 301 redirect to `http://NAME2/`?

Comment: I guess so to :) just looked up how to do it. Never done it something like this thx for help