# When changing my domain name, can I preserve all the Google +1?

Tags: google-plus, domain-transfer

My website has the Swedish TLD but is focused on a Dutch audience. Google sees it as Swedish. So I have to transfer from `Bloei.se` to `Bloeise.nl`. I see the following steps and have some additional questions:

**STEPS**

- Get my backlink profile
- Change or ask for changes on any links I can
- Implement 301's for the best links I can't change.

Would I also need 301's for links shared on G+?
Can I transfer the pluses my page got or do I have to start all over?

Comment: [Everything in this question except for the Google+ part has already been asked and answered](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I checked before posting but not good enough. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google+ page that you have setup then you can simply change the domain name of that page to the new site to preserve the +1's, if this has been done soley on the domain name and not to an existing Google+ business page then there is no way at this time to preserve the +1's across a domain name change.