# Shared hosting on same IP = loss of ranking when moving from domain A to domain B?

Tags: seo, google, domains, pagerank, ranking

I've read this thread: [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank)

Unfortunately, I can't find an answer to the following situation - and I am also explaining why:

I am moving a website from domain A to domain B and I am following the best practices mentioned in the other thread.

What the other thread is unfortunately not considering:

The old and the new domain are both part of the same shared hosting package and have therefore the same IP.

Will this hurt my Google ranking? Should I choose another host for the new domain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is posted twice. Do not do this. If you want to discuss your last post, that is fine. Leave comments. But posting multiple times can really turn the community against you.

Comment: I've deleted the other question before and rewrote the question as the first one was obviously misunderstood as a duplicate - which it isn't. I don't want to offend anybody. I'm desperately trying to get an answer.

Comment: Okay. However, the thing to do in the future is re-edit your original question and post a comment explaining how it is not a duplicate. The moderators can always reopen any question. Otherwise, people might think you are trying to game the community.

Comment: BTW- The IP address and host package will have nothing to do with rank except for trust issues. Changing domain names will break rank since it is each domain that rank is tied to. You will have to preserve the old domain name and 301 redirect it to the new site carefully to preserve any rank. Otherwise, it will all be lost and you will be starting over- which is not always such a bad thing, assuming that the old domain was not performing well.

Comment: Thank you, closetnoc, understood for the future ;-)

And for your answer. The 301s are prepared and also the change of address option in the webmaster tools.

And I know that in general, the IP and hosting package doesn't have an impact on page rank. 

I was just wondering whether the redirects plus the change of domain name could have a negative impact when using the same IP for the old AND the new domain.

Comment: And again  - as written in the question: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. I've read the thread and it doesn't even mention the string "IP" on the whole page. Nor does the linked Google article....

Comment: You should be okay. In fact, the IP address not changing may be a good thing assuming that the IP address is not in a blacklist or any site using that IP address has made Google mad. Odds are in your favor. The same goes for the host. Google does look for host quality and assuming you are not using a nasty host, you should be good.