# What should I do in Google search console after migrating to a new domain? Add the new site?

Tags: google-search-console

So my client wants to add google search console in the website. The site has been migrated from http://www.somedomain.com to http://www.somenewdomain.com.

Everything from the old site redirects to the new one. I have put a verification file in the root of new website what should I do to cater those redirects?

Should I create a new one? Don't seem to understand this.

Comment: You can check this link also for details: [How do I rename a domain and preserve PageRank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/how-do-i-rename-a-domain-and-preserve-pagerank)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you will need to tell Google that your site is moving domain.

[Information on the change of address tool in Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)

You should also have a separate Search Console property for every version of your website (this includes www. non www. https etc.).

[SEO 101: Which URL versions to add to Google Search Console](https://searchengineland.com/seo-101-url-versions-add-google-search-console-282463)